# How to change PlaceAutocomplete api key programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

I am using `PlaceAutocomplete` for search location. Now I have integrated `PlaceAutocomplete` for search and now i am getting location through this, Now I am setting `Google Places Api key` in manifest file using `<meta-date>` like,

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

Here is the Code to show search screen.

```
        try {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
```

Now I want to change `Google Places Api key` when i got new API key from my server API response. So *is it possible to change API key using code?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO, there is no way to set that programmatically right now.**

Google documentation:

> To access the Google Maps servers with the Maps API V2, you have to
>   add a Maps API key to your application.... Add the key to your
>   application by adding an element to your application's
>   `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Read it carefully, the notice is very very clear and you have no way to use other things rather than this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

For more clarification read:
[Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application)

Comment: Is it possible through Url request??

Comment: No, it's not possible in any way.

Comment: Well explained!

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot change `<meta-data>` programatically. It can only be set at Compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> How to change `PlaceAutocomplete` `API` key programically

**Not possible to change `PlaceAutocomplete` `API` key programically**

as [**documentation suggest**](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) the `API` key has to be assigned using the `Manifest` file:

[image]

[image]

for more information read from **[Get an API key from the Google API Console](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup)**